# How to set session component for CConsoleApplication in YII framework

Tags: php, yii, cmd

Trying to execute the the code using command line. After execution it gives error -

```
exception 'CException' with message 'Property "CConsoleApplication.session" is not defined.'
```

When the application is run on web everything works fine but not from command line.

Below is my code:

```
class CustomComponent{
public static function CustomMethod($arg){
   for($i = 1; $i<=$arg; $i++){
        $img = new Img();
        // Set static values for the variables
        $img->title = 'Test Title - '.$i;
        $img->data = 'Some test data';
        // Save data in database and create image.
        $img->save();
        Img::saveInSession($img->id);
        if($logo_path = $img->logo_image) {
        Img::embedLogo($img->image_path, $logo_path);
   }
    // Print message after successful generation of images.
    echo "Image ID - ".$img->id." GENERATED \n";
  }
    exit;
  }
}
```

When I execute this from command line it throws the above error when `saveInSession()` function is executed.

Any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: What code are you trying to execute? what did you try to find a solution?

Comment: Please check the edited post above. I am trying to run the code from `cmd` but I get the error when `saveInSession()` is executed. I resolved this by simply commenting the line. But didn't find any proper solution to resolve this.

Comment: Is `saveInSession` part of the `Img`class? Please post that too.

Comment: Also `if($logo_path = $img->logo_image)` shouldn't it be a `==`?

Comment: There is no error with `if($logo_path = $img->logo_image)` code as it gets executed properly. And yes `saveInSession` is a public function defined in `Img` class.  


               `public static function saveInSession($id) {  
                $arr = Yii::app()->session['in_session_img'] ? Yii::app()->session['in_session_img'] : array();  
            $arr[] = $id;  
            Yii::app()->session['in_session_img'] = $arr;  
        }`